# Undefined Match Found in Perl Regex Array

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string (e.g. '24G22') which I am trying to split into separate elements of numbers and character (i.e. 24, G, 22). For which, I wrote the regular expression as shown below.

However, for some weird reason, I get alot of undefined elements in my array which I had expected to be of the form:

@array = ('24','G', '22')

instead of

@array = ('24', undef, undef, 'G', '22', undef)

which I get from the output

Could someone help explain to me the cause of the error and how I could rectify the error and get my desired output?

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '24G22';
my @array = ( $string =~ m/([0-9]+)|([ATGCN]+)/g );
print join("\n", @array);
```

---

**Output**

```
$ ./test_debug.pl
Use of uninitialized value $array[1] in join or string at ./test_debug.pl line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $array[2] in join or string at ./test_debug.pl line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $array[5] in join or string at ./test_debug.pl line 8.
24


G
22
```

Comment: Why the heck was the OP downvoted for this question?? It is a well-presented question with a clear example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group in one group:

```
my @array = ( $string =~ m/([0-9]+|[ATGCN]+)/g );
```

because you have to catch only one group for each match.

With yours, you're matching 2 groups each times and one of them is empty.